# Why is my joomla site returning 403 Forbidden error after migration to new host?

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, migration

I recently attempted to migrate a Joomla based site from one host (where it was the primary domain) to a new hosting account where it is one of several add-on domains. Since I migrated the site files and database to the new host, I get a 403 forbidden error whenever I try to access it.

I've tried checking the file permissions and tinkering with htaccess, all to no avail. I suspect it may have something to do with the change in the file path, but I'm not sure what information would need to be updated or where.

I'm *very* unfamiliar with Joomla, but have a basic understanding of the file structure as it is similar to Wordpress which I have used pretty extensively.

Here is a link to the "domain" (the actual domain hasn't been pointed to this host yet):

```
107.180.54.175/~fatimamaster/fondationalfredbeliard.org/
```

If there's any pertinent information I have left out that would be helpful, please don't hesitate to let me know!

Any/all advice or suggestions are welcome and appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Moving the site among directories/sub-directories - Joomla Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Moving_the_site_among_directories/sub-directories)

Answer (score 0):

403 errors are usually permission related, I think the most likely causes are how you moved your Joomla site, or how the domain has been configured on the gaining server.

My suggestion is that it will save time if you use Akeeba Backup to make an archive copy of your site and then use it to install your site on your new server.

(1) Install [Akeeba Backup](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/akeeba-backup/), make a backup of your site and download the .jpa archive.

(2) You are probably familiar with the process of moving a domain from one server to another: setup your domain on the gaining server, update name servers with your domain registrar to point to the new server. Expect it to take +/- 24 hrs for the change to propagate and traffic to be directed to your new server.

(3) Delete any files and databases that you had previously installed on your new server. confirm that you can access an index.html file at your domain on the new server.

(4) Use Akeeba Backup to restore your site on your new server, [here's one link to walk you through the process](https://www.akeebabackup.com/videos/1212-akeeba-backup-core/1618-abtc04-restore-site-new-server.html)

My reasoning for starting the process over again is that steps 2 & 3 will identify any problems that might exist with the domain config on your new server, and step 4 will eliminate almost all Joomla specific problems.

Good luck!